# python find all common patterns in an array

Tags: python

In python how can i develop this algorithm to find common patterns in a text which is in an array and say that these are the number of occurences of those items.

```
  For ex:
line_arr=""" :)hello hi there,My name is 'pixel' can i speak to 'Tom'
Hi, tom here :) 'pixel'
how are u doing today.
i just called to ask whats the cost of the microwae oven is it $50 or $60
it is $75
any d $iscounts on this..
10% to 30%"""

reg_dict={}
for l in line_arr:
    #find all common patterns and update it in an dictionary
```

Can we get all smileys,names in single quotes,currecncy starting with $ and percentages..Also if any more common things.and say we update this in a dictionary..Is this possible at all..

Comment: its a very complicated program so i didnt mention it.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a string, not an array. You should tokenize it first. Once you've done that, you can use `collections.Counter.most_common`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import re
>>> Counter(re.findall("\w+", line_arr)).most_common()[:5]
[('is', 3), ('to', 3), ('pixel', 2), ('it', 2), ('i', 2)]
```

If you want to find smileys, use a different tokenizer than the RE `\w+` that I used above.

Comment: Cool thanks..i can take it further from here.....